# Bootstrap col-md-4 not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

What should be 3 columns only shows up as 1 column. Removing col-md-12  doesn't help. I've also tried changing container to container-fluid. I use NetBeans 8.1

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ddz8HjF.jpg">
          <h2>Manufacturing & Quality</h2>
          <p>Flextron’s manufacturing facility is well
            <br>equipped with fully and semi-automatic
            <br>hi-tech equipments capable of placing
            <br>variety of SMT and Through-Hole components
            <br>on Flexible and Rigid PCBs.
            <br>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qpakutc.jpg">
          <h2>Our Capabilities</h2>
          <p>We offer the latest in SMT, THT, BGA and
            <br>Micro-BGA capability, in addition to mixed
            <br>technology PCB assembly. Keeping on the
            <br>forefront of component requirements, we
            <br>offer surface mount placement down to 12 mil
            <br>pitch, with a component range of 0201 to 52
            <br>mm square QFPs and BGAs....
            <br>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ddz8HjF.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nested columns require a row

Comment: I tried removing the col-md-12 so it would no longer be nested, but it didn't work. I also tried adding a row div after the col-md-12 but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3):

Your viewport isn't wide enough for `col-md-*` classes to work.

Check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m7s3pnt3/

If you replace it with `col-sm-*` classes, it'll align in three columns.

Comment: I tried using col-sm and col-xs but neither seem to work

Comment: Joel's does work. Scott is also correct that you should never have a column inside of a column without another row in between. You don't need the col-md-12 in this case. Try posting your example in a jsfiddle if you're still having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the following classes to each of my col-md-4 divs:

- d-block
- mx-auto